# How do i create a BindingList from a DataGridView.DataSource

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource, bindinglist

I have a DataGridView that some data have been binded to it and i don't know the type of binded data.
Now, i want to create a BindlingList that contains all the rows binded to the DataGridView;
I mean :

```
BindingList<???> list = new BindingList<???>(/*the list of data binded to grid*/);
```

what shall i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
BindingList<???> list = new BindingList<???>();
foreach(??? item in DataSource)
{
   //list.Add(item.Clone());
   //list.Add(new ???(item));   
   //you can't add an item that already was binded, 
   //so you have to create a new instance, 
   //consider implement clone method in ??? and use it
}
```